# Validate 'select option' values serverside

Tags: php, html

Would it be a good idea to check serverside whether the option values submitted from html are valid? Or am I over-engineering here?

**HTML**

```
<select name="options">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
$allowed = array('foo','bar','baz');
if(!in_array($_POST['options'], $allowed)) {
    //display error
    die();
}
```

Comment: You could get an error in another function when handling the input, and you should always check user input. So no, not over-engineering.

Comment: No you're not. It's a good idea, but only if it's necessary. And only you would know that.

Comment: @Qurben And there's XSS and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `(` in if statment.

```
if(!in_array($_POST['options'], $allowed) {
    //display error
}
```

use it.

```
if(!in_array($_POST['options'], $allowed)) {
    //display error
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's not the code itself I'm worried about. Thanks for your answer tho ;)